# exact year difference between two nsdates

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am taking two NSDates from datepicker
I want to calculate the exact year difference between the dates..if I change the second date's day one greater, it should give me the year difference 2..and if take the day lesser it should give me 0 year difference..how can I achieve that? please help me..

this is my code to calculate difference

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];


    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *components1 = [gregorian1 components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:startDate
                                                  toDate:endDate options:0];
    NSInteger diff = [components1 year];
```

Comment: And what's your issue? With what date did you tried? Do you have some values tested, loggued?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                       fromDate:dateA
                                         toDate:dateB
                                        options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference in date components: %i/%i/%i", components.day, components.month, components.year);
```

As the result you have difference in date components.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
extension Date{
    func yearsTo(_ date : Date) -> Int{
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: self, to: date).year ?? 0
    }
}
```